# How to get on('mousedown', ....) from the child element in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, draggable, drag, children, directive

I got this simple drag example from angularjs docs. 
here is a

```
plunk fork
```

However, I am trying to get to the child node's actions so it will drag only when clicked on the child element. I have tried :

```
var elementDrag=element[0].getElementsByClassName('dragThis');
elementDrag.on('mousedown', function(event) {
  // Prevent default dragging of selected content
  event.preventDefault();
  startX = event.pageX - x;
  startY = event.pageY - y;
  $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
  $document.on('mouseup', mouseup); 
});
```

Any ideas on how to approach this without using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty implementation to get you started with: http://plnkr.co/edit/1hBmpg51xqzxi0EP4WBg

Try it out and let me know if you still have questions. The controller code needs some cleaning ;-).

The implementation is based on two directives that communicate with each other. The outer directive (draggable-content) exposes an API allowing the inner directive (draggable-control) to perform de drag.

```
.directive('draggableControl', function($document) {
  return {
    require: '^draggableContent',
    // The 4th arg of the link fn, ctrl, is the controller of the outer directive draggableContent
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        // more code
        }
    };
})
```

The markup is straightforward:

```
<body ng-app="drag">
    <div draggable-content>
    <div draggable-control class="dragThis" style='border: 1px solid yellow; background:white;'>Drag here only</div>
    DO NOT drag here<br><br><br>or here</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, Ill see if I can make the controller work.  I was playing with event.layerY and checking the initial click position. Your answers gives me more clues.

Comment: I just realized I had not saved the plunkr. please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @apairet plunkr, I was able to finish the directive. 
Here is what I fixed:

```
      function mouseup() {
        $document.off('mousemove', ctrl.mousemove);
        $document.off('mouseup', mouseup);
        ctrl.y = event.screenY - ctrl.startY;
        ctrl.x = event.screenX - ctrl.startX;
      }
```

Thank you, I learned about "^require".